# Twitter API 1.1 gives error code 32

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth

So. I'm trying to get all statuses from a list feed. To be more specific, this one https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/lists/statuses

It's using the OAuth 1.0a, as far as I know.
My problem is, that I get an errorcode 32.

I'm using following code:

```
<?php function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) { 
    $r = array(); 
    ksort($params); 
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    } 
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r)); 
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array(); 
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value) 
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values); 
    return $r; 
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json?slug=danskere-i-udlandet&owner_screen_name=d_fodbold&count=20";
$oauth_access_token = "29194047-Dzwsoo1KiQg69dbabt3nS2ezjjNzlbZdlKpLWsOOG"; 
$oauth_access_token_secret = "secret"; 
$consumer_key = "iCV8UbKjmq9LAw1XIvTQ"; 
$consumer_secret = "secret";
$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                'oauth_nonce' => md5(microtime()), 
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1', 
                'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token, 
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(), 
                'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth); 

$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret); 
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true)); 
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

// Make Requests 
$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)); 
$options = array(   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header, 
                //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields, 
                    CURLOPT_HEADER => false, 
                    CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);


$feed = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options); 
$json = curl_exec($feed); 
curl_close($feed);


$twitter_data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($twitter_data);
exit();?>
```

I can't figure what the problem is there.

I hope some of you can.

Comment: My guess is that the error is in the querystring in $url. i just can't seem to figure what it is. I'm not that experienced with cURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out. The way the baseline was made, wasn't right.

The querystring has to be included in it, and sorted alphabetic.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your `oauth_nonce`. I don't think that `md5(microtime())` is a good nonce generator. Try to do like the Twitter Developers documentation says about [authorizing requests](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) :

> The oauth_nonce parameter is a unique token your application should
>   generate for each unique request. Twitter will use this value to
>   determine whether a request has been submitted multiple times. The
>   value for this request was generated by base64 encoding 32 bytes of
>   random data, and stripping out all non-word characters, but any
>   approach which produces a relatively random alphanumeric string should
>   be OK here.

Comment: `md5(microtime())` is usually fine. However, `uniqid()` would be even better.